# Hibernate assertionFailure, null identifier

Tags: hibernate

I am using the following:

- spring-boot 2.7.17
- hibernate 5.6.15.Final

I have an Entity DokVerweis with the PK:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID_VERWEIS", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Override
public String getVerweisId() {
    return verweisId;
}
```

It is an older program so we are using hibernate manually. So we merge entities with:

```
entityManager.merge(entity);
```

I have a log-message directly bevor the merge.

Here is the part of the log:

```
Merge: DokVerweis [verweisId=a34869e5-3252-406b-ac24-e9f7bbfca949, dokumentId=e18fada6-b4c1-4011-977d-9a7913e263f2, sortindex=0]
HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more 
likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
```

The PK (verweisId) is filled. Anyone has a hint what else that error message could mean?

Comment: Could solve my problem. Needed to change an OneToOne relation in DokVerweis to cascade = CascadeType.ALL